# Distilling summary statistics by numerical categories with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a large (rows > 200000) data frame with dozens of columns of data.  I want to distill this data frame down and summarize the number of data that have variables that fall within given ranges.

For instance, if I have a `data.frame` that is similar to this:

```
 set.seed(10)
 df <- data.frame( age = runif( n = 1000, min = 0, max = 4000 ),
                   size = rnorm( n = 1000, mean = 10, sd = 1 ),
                   shape = rnorm( n = 1000, mean = 1000, sd = 1000) )
```

and I would like to group get the `number` of samples within a series of age ranges, the mean `size` and `shape`, and the median `size` and `shape` from the samples in each of those age brackets.

Something like

```
 summary.df <- data.frame( age.group = seq( 0, 3900, by = 100 ),
                           number = (number of samples in age bin),
                           mean = ( mean of data in age bin ) )
```

etc.

Right now I am doing this very bluntly by creating a new `data.frame` for each age group.

```
data.1          <- subset( df, age > 0 & age <= 100 )
data.2          <- subset( df, age > 100 & age <= 200 )
data.3          <- subset( df, age > 200 & age <= 300 )
```

etc.
and then adding a categorical variable

```
data.1 <- data.frame( data.1, age.group = "100", count.row = nrow( data.1 ) )
data.2 <- data.frame( data.2, age.group = "200", count.row = nrow( data.2 ) )
data.3 <- data.frame( data.3, age.group = "300", count.row = nrow( data.3 ) )
```

adding them together

```
data.big <- rbind( data.1, data.2, data.3 )
```

and then generating summary stats via `dplyr`

```
data.summary <- data.big %>%
   group_by( age.group ) %>%
   summarize( count.row = mean( count.row ),
         mean = mean( size, na.rm = TRUE ),
         median = median( size, na.rm = T ) )
```

How would I go about doing this more efficiently with just `dplyr`?  I think there must be a way but I can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `cut` to divide the data in intervals of 100 and calculate summary statistics for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(age = cut(age, seq( 0, 4000, by = 100))) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean( size, na.rm = TRUE),
            median = median( size, na.rm = TRUE))

#   age          mean median
#   <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 (0,100]     10.0    9.92
# 2 (100,200]    9.88  10.2 
# 3 (200,300]   10.1   10.1 
# 4 (300,400]    9.83   9.80
# 5 (400,500]    9.95   9.72
# 6 (500,600]    9.68   9.78
# 7 (600,700]   10.2   10.5 
# 8 (700,800]   10.2   10.4 
# 9 (800,900]    9.68   9.47
#10 (900,1e+03]  9.80   9.81
# … with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks!  As a quick followup, is there a way to add a column that is an age variable that is the minimum of the particular age bin? Also, what function gives the number of observations in the cut dataset?

Comment: If you want to find minimum of `age` variable, change the grouping to `group_by(age_group = cut(age, seq( 0, 4000, by = 100)))` so that we don't overwrite the `age` variable and use `min_age = min(age, na.rm = TRUE)` to get minimum age and `count = n()` to count number of observations in `summarise`.